# Symfony2 installation: symfony.webconfigurator service

Tags: php, symfony, service

I try to configure symfony2 on wamp, but I get a mistake:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The service "symfony.webconfigurator" does not exist.' in F:\xamppx\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\app\bootstrap.php:112 Stack trace: 
#0 F:\xamppx\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\vendor\bundles\Symfony\Bundle\WebConfiguratorBundle\SymfonyWebConfiguratorBundle.php(28): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('symfony.webconf...') 
#1 F:\xamppx\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\app\bootstrap.php(543): Symfony\Bundle\WebConfiguratorBundle\SymfonyWebConfiguratorBundle->boot() 
#2 F:\xamppx\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\app\bootstrap.php(559): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() 
#3 F:\xamppx\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\web\app_dev.php(15): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request)) 
#4 {main} thrown in F:\xamppx\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\app\bootstrap.php on line 112
```

Why?

Comment: Symfony2 is not stable yet. Currently things change every day. You should wait for stable release. The message tells you that symfony.webconfigurator service is not known to Dependency Injection Container.

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this,

This is the official Symfony2 repository is hosted on Github

Link: https://github.com/symfony/symfony

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Symfony Standard 2.0.0 PR7 .tgz ? Try Symfony Standard 2.0.0 PR7 .zip, i fixed this issue with.

Answer (score 0):

i have this error to...
You have to take .zip arvive of PR8
Take vendor, change config, appKeernel and autoload
to finish, in comand line run the build/build_bootstrap.php